# In Rails, how do I visit a URL with a POST method and submit some XML data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

For example, in Rails, I want to visit the url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/update` with the HTTP method POST, and submit XML data. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this via a web service than you would need to make sure your controller can respond to a request for updating with xml (by making sure the update method has a format clause with xml specified) and then in your code just make a request to the url and set the appropriate http headers.  That's really all you need.